# Android - Broadcast receiver not detecting PHONE_STATE_CHANGED when app is closed

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-11

I am trying to develop an app that detects incoming call and announce the name of the caller. The broadcast receiver that I have used works fine when the app is in foreground. But when I close the app, it doesn't detect the phone state although I have declared it in my manifest.

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CallAnnouncer"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".ExcludeActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SMSActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CallActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PermissionActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Speaker"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
```

**CallReceiver.java**

```
Context context1;
String savedNumber, name, incomeNumber;
private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
static boolean isIncoming;
Boolean isAdded = false;
SharedPreferences prefs;

@SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context1 = context;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                isAdded = prefs.getBoolean("added", false);
                incomeNumber = prefs.getString("number", null);
                if (isAdded) {
                    onStateChanged(context, state, incomeNumber, intent);
                    editor.putString("number", incomeNumber);
                } else {
                    onStateChanged(context, state, incomingNumber, intent);
                    editor.putString("number", incomingNumber);
                }
                editor.putBoolean("added", !isAdded);
                editor.apply();
            } else
                incomeNumber = incomingNumber;
            onStateChanged(context, state, incomingNumber, intent);
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

public void onStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number, Intent intent) {
    if (lastState == state) {
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            Date callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, intent);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, intent);
            }

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    onMissedCall(context, incomeNumber, new Date(), intent);
                } else
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, new Date(), intent);
            } else if (isIncoming) {
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, new Date(), intent);
            } else {
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, new Date(), intent);
            }

            break;
    }

    lastState = state;
}

protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    name = getContactName(number);
    Intent ttsService = new Intent(ctx, Speaker.class);
    ttsService.putExtra("text", "You have call from " + name);
    ctx.startService(ttsService);
}

protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    Intent ttsService = new Intent(ctx, Speaker.class);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        ttsService.putExtra("text", "You have a missed call");
    } else {
        name = getContactName(number);
        ttsService.putExtra("text", "You have missed call from " + name);
    }
    ctx.startService(ttsService);
    //            saveData(ctx, number, intent, "Missed Call");
}

protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    name = getContactName(number);
    Log.d("TAG", "Outgoing Call to " + name);
}

protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    name = getContactName(number);
    Log.d("TAG", "Incoming call ended of " + name);
}

protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Intent intent) {
    name = getContactName(number);
    Log.d("TAG", "Outgoing Call ended of " + name);
}

private String getContactName(String phone) {
    ContentResolver cr = context1.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        name = cursor.getString(0);
    } else {
        name = "unknown number";
    }

    if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return name;
}
```

**SpeakerService.java:**

```
TextToSpeech tts = null;
String spokenText;
Boolean isInit = false;
HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<>();

private static final String TAG = "TTS_Service";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null)
        spokenText = intent.getStringExtra("text");
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int i) {
    if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onInit: TextToSpeech Success");
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result != TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA && result != TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onInit: speaking........");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                        String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    tts.speak(spokenText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                } else {
                    tts.speak(spokenText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
            isInit = true;
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "onInit: TTS initialization failed");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: According to your use case, you must keep the APP in the foreground or running in the background, in order to keep the app in the foreground, there is some restriction on the Android System side, so use work manager to handle that

Comment: @Prasath but I really want to make it work when app is closed as call can come at any time so app should be able to detect it whether in foreground or background and it works in both scenarios but when I kill the app or close it, the broadcaster also stops